# Read gdb into shiny app

Tags: r, file-geodatabase, api, gui, shiny

I want to access a feature class inside a geodatabase (gdb) from inside my shinyapp. I can access the fc class once I provide the gdb path:

```
 gdb_data = arcgisbinding::arc.open(gdb)
```

but how do I get the information of the path to my gdb as in input in my shiny app? fileInput doesn't work as a .gdb acts like a folder. I tried the package `shinyFiles` but that did not lead to success, as I could not navigate to **any drive** (I remained in Home, could not navigate to any depth in the files). I used this https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-directory-input/29160/2 as a template.

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 mainPanel(       
            shinyDirButton("dir", "Input gdb", "Input gdb"),
            verbatimTextOutput("dir", placeholder = TRUE)          
          )
        )
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  shinyDirChoose(
    input,
    'dir',
    roots = c(home = '~'),
    filetypes = c('', 'txt', 'bigWig', "tsv", "csv", "bw")
  )

  global <- reactiveValues(datapath = getwd())
  
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  
  output$dir <- renderText({
    global$datapath
  })
  
  observeEvent(ignoreNULL = TRUE,
               eventExpr = {
                 input$dir    
               },
               handlerExpr = {
                 if (!"path" %in% names(dir())) return()
                 home <- normalizePath("~")
                 global$datapath <-
                   file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
               })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that if you specify:

```
roots = c(home = '~'),
```

then the shiny app won't let you break out of `~`, your home directory.

If you try:

```
roots = c(root="/"),
```

then you can get to the top of the file system (at least on a Linux box, I think it should translate to Windows/Mac) and go anywhere. Additionally you can do:

```
roots = c(root="/", home="~"),
```

and that gives two drop-down shortcuts to those locations in the chooser.

The reason for this is so you can create shiny apps and publish them and restrict user's ability to get to arbitrary locations on the server. If you have a folder `/public/` with data (or a selection of gdb folders) in it and only want users to choose from those, set that as the `roots` vector and they won't be able to get to `/restricted/` or other locations. Except they might and deploying a shiny app to the public on a server with restricted data would not be a the best thing in the world to do.

If this is all for single-user consumption and your shiny port isn't open to the outside world then set `roots` to "/" and go anywhere...

Comment: thanks!! It helped me to find the root of the problem. In the end I am using the answer of https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles/issues/85 to get all volumes loaded: As your solution did enable me to go to further depth in the files but I was not able to go to different (network) drives on my PC

Comment: I now got the correct path to my .gdb but I can't load it. It gives me the `Error in .call_proxy: cannot open dataset`. I open the gdb with `arcgisbinding::arc_open(global$datapath)` and I run `arcgisbinding::arc.check_product()` before (both on the server side).